# Eclipse/GTK+ wasting screen real estate

Tags: eclipse, gtk

Eclipse on Linux (GTK+) has rather large UI elements which wastes screen real estate. Compare the Linux version (taken on Ubuntu 9.10):

[image]

with the Windows version:

[image]

Note the vertical size of the Project Explorer tab, the menubar, and the toolbar. Is it possible to tweak this somehow? How does this look in other Linux distributions?

Comment: This. Is in fact the most annoying thing about eclipse, 2 years and still looks ugly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some blog entries for making Eclipse GTK gui less "clumsy". Note that you have to modify the gtkrc file in most cases:

- [Making Eclipse good on Linux](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MakingEclipseLookGoodOnLinuxRevisited)
- [Tweaking Eclipse UI](http://farjumper.livejournal.com/3855.html)
- [Smaller font sizes for Eclipse on Linux](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/)

Comment: Thanks. Modifying the rc-file was something I expected I had to do.